# Where to use std::variant over union?

Tags: c++, c++17, union, variant, std-variant

Please explain what is the difference between `union` and `std::variant` and why  `std::variant` was introduced into the standard? In what situations should we use `std::variant` over the old-school `union`?

Comment: I think `union` does not allow non-POD objects inside. And even if it kinda does (i.e. program does not crash immediately), it does not ensure that correct destructor is called.

Comment: Everywhere you want type safety and are working with non-trivial types.

Comment: I got contradiction and misconception about std::variant while watching this video by Jason Turner:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wm5QzdddYc

Comment: @yeputons, You can store non-POD objects in a union, but you're responsible for constructing and destroying objects when switching the active member. A union is a common implementation technique for in-place storage in types like `std::optional` and, you guessed it, `std::variant`.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should prefer `variant` unless one of the following comes up:

1. You're cheating. You're doing type-punning or other things that are UB but you're hoping your compiler won't break your code.
2. You're doing some of the pseudo-punnery that C++ `union`s are allowed to do: conversion between layout-compatible types or between common initial sequences.
3. You explicitly need layout compatibility. `variant<Ts>` are not required to have any particular layout; `unions` of standard layout types are standard layout.
4. You need low-level support for in-place switching of objects. Using a memory buffer for such things doesn't provide the trivial copying guarantees that you could get out of a `union`.

The basic difference between the two is that `variant` *knows* which type it stores, while `union` expects you to keep track of that externally. So if you try to access the wrong item in a `variant`, you get an exception or `nullptr`. By contrast, doing so with a `union` is merely undefined behavior.

`union` is a lower-level tool, and thus should only be used when you absolutely need that lower-level.

`variant` also has machinery for doing visitation, which means you get to avoid having a bunch of `if` statements where you ask "if it is type X, do this. If it is type Y, do that, etc".

Comment: "merely undefined behavior" is not a phrase I see very often. :-) *Excellent* answer, though. "Cheating" is the primary motivation here, and seems to largely encompass 2 and 4 as well.

Comment: @CodyGray: #2 and #4 are both perfectly legal. They're not really cheating so much as things that look like they're cheating.

Comment: Is there an overhead to using std::variant compared to using an union?

Comment: @In78: Of course there is. A union doesn't have to know what type it stores, but a variant does. Therefore, there will at least be memory overhead from having that information.

Comment: Thanks for the honest and unassuming answer - refreshing to see coming from the C++ community.

Answer (score 0):

Variant has the support of RAII , so the destructor is called when the object goes out of scope. This RAII is useful in case of automatic resource management.