# std::variant of classes with same base class

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I'm not fully comprehending variants' usage, maybe someone can clear up what I'm doing wrong (possibly my approach).

Let the variant object be _Types of two classes, both inheriting the same class.

```
class base
{
public:
    int foo;
};
class a: public base
{
    int bar;
};
class b: public base
{
    float bar;
};

byte variant_id = 0; // 0 for class A, 1 for class B
std::variant< base, a, b > variant;
```

Here's how I use the variant:

```
void func( )
{
    auto& _variant = std::get< base >( variant ); // ideally would be = variant_id ? std::get< b >( variant ) : std::get< a >( variant )
    _variant.foo = 20;

    if ( variant_id == 1 )
    {
        auto& variant_ = std::get< b >( variant );
        variant_.bar = 20.f;
    }
    else
    {
        auto& variant_ = std::get< a >( variant );
        variant_.bar = 20;
    }
```

Maybe a union is more effective?

```
union
{
    a _a;
    b _b;
} variant;
byte variant_id = 0;
```

Comment: How will you find a `type` of data stored in `union`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase?

Comment: wouldn't a simple base class and virtual `func()` be better for something like this?

Comment: func is independent of the classes. It cannot be virtual as it is implemented elsewhere

Comment: right, but if you're wanting to do different things depending on the sub-class, wouldn't you want to move it to a virtual member function and use it that way?

Comment: @CryptographyMan `variant` helps to get last assigned data type. I think there is not way to get data type from `union`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try not to query the variant for what type it holds. If you do, your code is essentially equivalent to a bunch of dynamic casts in an if chain, a code smell.

Instead, let the variant dispatch for you. And if you want to access the common `base` of `a` and `b`, you do not need a `base` member in that variant.

Use a visitor

```
std::variant< a, b > var;
void func( )
{
   std::visit([](auto&& v) {
     v.foo = 20; // Both `a` and `b` have a foo, this is well formed.
     v.bar = 20; // Both have a `bar` that can be assigned a 20. This is well formed too
   }, var);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Koehler has given a good answer for some technical errors in your usage, but I feel variant is the wrong tool for the job here.

Typically, you would use an `std::variant` for unrelated datatypes. Is there a reason to use variant here? Since you are only holding sub-classes of `base`, you'd usually opt for a `std::unique_ptr<base>` or `std::shared_ptr<base>` (depending on the requirements) and be done with it.

The only reason I'd see to use a variant of sub-classes would be to ensure they can be stored contiguously to reduce memory/indirection costs. And even then, I'd use it through the base class interface, like so:

```
base& getBase(std::variant<a, b>& v)
{
   // the conditional here might be omitted in the generated
   // code since the branches might be identical
   return v.index() == 0 ? std::get<a>(v) : std::get<b>(v);
}

// use like
base& b = getBase(variant);
b.func(20);
```

Answer (score 2):

What `std::variant` does for you is to track what the current (last assigned) type is, and complain when you try to get a different type. So instead of tracking `variant_id` you should be using `variant.index()`.

Also I believe that your first extraction of `base` will actually fail if the type assigned is not of the `base` type. Assuming your objects will always be of type `a` or `b` (and never `base`), you should drop the `base` type from the variant type constructor.

I'm assuming here that you are not creating classes `base`, `a` and `b` yourself (and can't touch them), and thus the virtual method approach isn't viable.

Comment: so if these two classes have something in common, e.g. foo, how can I dynamically assign a variable to these two types? i.e. `auto& variant_` in the OP.

Comment: See StoryTeller's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

`Variant` knows which type it stores. `Union` expects you are keeping the track of that type externally. If you try to access the wrong item in a `variant`, you get an `exception` or `nullptr`, for the `Union` it is merely undefined behavior.
([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082456/10035556))