# Implementing a symbol tables to store values for different types C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, casting, compiler-construction

I'm implementing a compiler in C++ and am at the AST stage. I now need to add in the symbol_entry, a value for that varible (it already has type). But how do I keep values of different sizes in an attributes of the class when I don't know the type. My current idea is to declare an attribute "val_pointer" of type void* in the symbol_entry, and cast for example from int* to void* and back. My understanding is that this can be done because pointers are all of the same size. Will this work? And also, is this way of allocating an int* separately each time efficient? I think that it would be better if I store create these int* from a contiguous block of memory, but I want to save space too.

Comment: A simple solution would be to use a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), with the tag being the type of the data.

Comment: How do you know which  real type these `void*` pointers must be casted to? Also I am not quite understanding, what you have there, is that supposed to be present at runtime?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did not think of your first question, that is a good point, but because I store the type I can write a function which manages which type to cast to from void*. I do not understand your second question. from what I think you're asking, yes the symbol_table needs to be there and keeps getting updated with new entries and upadtes on those entires at runtime.

Comment: @icebp I did not know about tagged unions. I think they will work, thank you.

Comment: @molereddy [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: @molereddy _"yes the symbol_table needs to be there and keeps getting updated with new entries and upadtes on those entires at runtime."_ Well, that's quite unusual for a compiled language, are you sure you're constructing a compiler, or is it more an interpreter?

Comment: Use some standard C++ [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think I misunderstood your usgae of the word runtime. I meant runtime when you are making an AST (I'm still at the AST-TAC level) from a particular input program, you have to have the symbol table updated for the the variables in the input. Not runtime as in executing the complied code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). For example:

```cpp
enum Type
{
    tInt,
    tDouble
};

struct Data
{
    Type    type;
    union
    {
        int Int;    // only valid when type is tInt
        double Double;  // only valid when type is tDouble
    } as;
};
```

Note that this isn't the best solution available in C++. You may want to look into [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), which has some advantages when compared to a raw tagged union, see [Where to use std::variant over union?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082328/where-to-use-stdvariant-over-union).

Another approach might be to have a class hierarchy, where each of your data types inherits from a basic `Object` type.